# Pandas duplicated and drop_duplicated does not work properly

Tags: python, pandas

The dataset named 'changes' was obtained from a merge by RID:

```
changes.head()

    DX_bl  RID  DX_m12
0      1    3       1
1      0    4       0
2      0    6       0
3      0    8       0
4      1   10       1
```

I've used the two following commands with the intention of identifying lines in which DX_bl and DX_m12 are different:

```
print(changes[~changes.duplicated(subset = ['DX_bl','DX_m12'], keep=False)])
print(changes.drop_duplicates(subset = ['DX_bl','DX_m12']))


    DX_bl  RID  DX_m12
64      1  167       0


    DX_bl  RID  DX_m12
0       1    3       1
1       0    4       0
10      0   30       1
64      1  167       0
```

If `keep=False`, it should return lines 10 (RID 30) and 64 (RID 64). But, as we can see, it loses the information of line 10 (RID 30).

On the other hand, if 'keep' is let in default option (`keep = 'first'`) it wrongly returns lines 0 (RID 3) and 1 (RID 4).

Is there a bug in pandas' duplicated/drop_duplicates??

Comment: please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, it will make it easier to check. Because you only posted changes.head(), I cant repro your case exactly.

Comment: looking at the docs, I think the 2 cases you posted are not equivalent. I will post an answer with my reasoning

Comment: print(changes[~changes.duplicated(subset = [['DX_bl','DX_m12']], keep=False)]) print(changes.drop_duplicates(subset = [['DX_bl','DX_m12']]))

Answer (score 0):

OK, i missed your comment "with the intention of identifying lines in which DX_bl and DX_m12 are different".

If you want to list all lines where these 2 columns differ, you can use this:

```
changes[changes['DX_bl'] != changes['DX_m12']]
```

or, equivalently:

```
changes.query('DX_bl != DX_m12')
```

From the data you've posted, it seems that duplicated() and drop_duplicates() are working as the documentation.